# Strstr Returning NULL

Tags: c, arrays, string, strstr

I am running into problems trying to use strstr with the following code. Can anyone point out to me why `strstr` on line 108 (documented in `printf()` statement) is returning NULL? I used a file as my command line argument (containing three words separated by \n and null terminated), and then used another file as `stdin`.

For example:

```
./stream_search word_list.txt < paragraph.txt
```

Goal: to print out all lines in paragraph.txt that contain the words in word_list.txt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INPUTSIZE 1000
#define LINESIZE 100

/*
    Read one line of a given file f into the array buffer.
 */
char* read_line(FILE* f, char buffer[LINESIZE]) {
    //reads line until n-1 char read, \n read, \o read, or EOF reached
    fgets(buffer, LINESIZE-1, f);
    printf("line 38: read line: %s\n", buffer);
    return buffer;
}

/*
   Prints the string in array buff.
*/
void print_buff(char buff[LINESIZE]) {
   printf("print_buff: %s\n", buff);
}

/* 
    Read lines from standard input and store in array p.
*/
char* get_input(char p[INPUTSIZE]) {
    fgets(p, INPUTSIZE-1, stdin);
    printf("line 76: %s\n", p);
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   char words[LINESIZE];
   char user_input[INPUTSIZE];

   /*
    * Prints error if program was called with 
    * no command line arguments,
    * or with more than one argument.
    */
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./stream_search <word list file> \n");
        return 0;
    }

    //assume argv[1] is a filename to open
    FILE* file = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    //Print error if file cannot be opened
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open word list \n");
        return 0;
    }

    read_line(file, words); //get input from file  
    get_input(user_input); //get input from stdin

    printf("line 98: %s", words);
    printf("line 101: %s", user_input);

    char* a = "hello";
    char* b = "hel";

    printf("line 103: %s\n", strstr(a, b));
    printf("line 108: %s\n", strstr(words, user_input));

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Line 108 means the code is quite long to be an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Line 108 is one of the printf messages in the MCVE the OP provided.

Comment: Most likely, the problem is that you didn't remove the newline at the end of the line read by `fgets()`.  Note that if the array is `char buffer[BUFLEN];`, it is perfectly safe and sane to use `fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, fp)`, specifying the full size of the array.

Comment: Could you cut the code down to just show the line returning null, and all related code specific for it.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper: The code when pulled from the question is actually about 70 lines long, not over 100, perhaps because the loops around the file reading operations were removed. You will note that I said "quite long", which is a very mild rebuke. Removing comments and so on can bring the code down to about 60 lines, and `print_buff()` is unused. It is worth doing that. The code could be simplified still further if the two input functions are combined because the size of the buffer is passed explicitly to the function. Then there's only one place where the newline stripping needs to be done.

Comment: The other problem is that the call to `strstr()` needs to be in the order `strstr(haystack, needle)`, not in the order `strstr(needle, haystack)` which is used in the code.  In other words, the call needs to be `strstr(user_input, words)` not `strstr(words, user_input)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in the code, either of which would prevent it from working as intended.

1. You don't remove the newline from the end of the word to be searched for (or the 'user input'), so the word would only be found if it appeared at the end of the input.
2. You call the function `strstr()` with the arguments in the wrong order.  The call needs to be needs to be in the order `strstr(haystack, needle)`, not in the order `strstr(needle, haystack)` which is used in the code.  In other words, the call needs to be `strstr(user_input, words)` not `strstr(words, user_input)`.

You have a function `print_buff()` that's not used.  You have two very similar functions that could be combined into one quite easily by passing the file stream and buffer size as arguments.  This would also give you one place to remove the newline.  Note that if the array is `char buffer[BUFLEN];`, it is perfectly safe and sane to use `fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, fp)` (and usually better to use `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)`), specifying the full size of the array.

Putting these changes together yields:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INPUTSIZE 1000
#define LINESIZE 100

static void read_line(FILE *f, size_t bufsiz, char buffer[])
{
    fgets(buffer, bufsiz, f);
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char words[LINESIZE];
    char user_input[INPUTSIZE];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./stream_search <word list file> \n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open word list \n");
        return 0;
    }

    read_line(file, sizeof(words), words);
    read_line(stdin, sizeof(user_input), user_input);

    printf("line 98: %s\n", words);
    printf("line 101: %s\n", user_input);
    printf("line 108: %s\n", strstr(words, user_input));
    printf("line 109: %s\n", strstr(user_input, words));

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that not all implementations of `printf()` handle null pointers gracefully; they are entitled to crash instead, and IMO it is better if they do.  However, I didn't fix that in this code — (un)fortunately, the system I'm using has a `printf()` that prints `(null)` instead of crashing when given a null pointer to print as a string.

Given a file `words` containing the line `hel` and the file `data` containing `hello world`, and calling the program `wm13`, I get the sample output:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
      -Wold-style-definition -Werror wm13.c -o wm13
$ ./wm13 words < data
line 98: hel
line 101: hello world
line 108: (null)
line 109: hello world
$
```